# Groupby apply with multiple arguments

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, apply, pandas-groupby

I'd like to calculate the percentile rank based on which Group they belongs to.  I have written the following codes and was able to calculate, say zscore as there is only one input.  What shall I do with a function which has two arguments?  Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np

funZScore = lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
funPercentile = lambda x, y: stats.percentileofscore(x[~np.isnan(x)], y)

A = pd.DataFrame({'Group' : ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B'], 
                  'Value' : [4, 7, None, 6, 2, 8, 1]})

# Compute the Z-score by group
A['Z'] = A.groupby('Group')['Value'].apply(funZScore)

print(A)
Group  Value         Z
0     A    4.0 -1.091089
1     A    7.0  0.872872
2     A    NaN       NaN
3     A    6.0  0.218218
4     B    2.0 -0.440225
5     B    8.0  1.144586
6     B    1.0 -0.704361

# compute the percentile rank by group
# how to put two arguments into groupby apply? 
# I hope to get something like below
Group  Value         Z    P
0     A    4.0 -1.091089    33.33
1     A    7.0  0.872872   100 
2     A    NaN       NaN   NaN
3     A    6.0  0.218218   66.67
4     B    2.0 -0.440225   66.67
5     B    8.0  1.144586   100
6     B    1.0 -0.704361   33.33
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need:

```
d = A.groupby('Group')['Value'].apply(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{'A': [4.0, 7.0, nan, 6.0], 'B': [2.0, 8.0, 1.0]}


A['P'] = A.apply(lambda x: funPercentile(np.array(d[x['Group']]), x['Value']), axis=1)
print (A)
  Group  Value         Z           P
0     A    4.0 -1.091089   33.333333
1     A    7.0  0.872872  100.000000
2     C    NaN       NaN         NaN
3     A    6.0  0.218218   66.666667
4     B    2.0 -0.440225   66.666667
5     B    8.0  1.144586  100.000000
6     B    1.0 -0.704361   33.333333
```

Comment: I guess my original post wasn't clear.  I have edited it.

Comment: @Lafayette - What is value `y` ?

Comment: the percentileofscore function from scipy.stats requires 2 inputs.  it's basically the respective value from the 'Value' column.  Not sure how to reference to that.

Comment: @Lafayette - I am confused, I check [`percentileofscore`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html) and parameter `score`, in your function it is `y` is scalar, e.g. `3` and values from `Value` column is `x`

Comment: It is like `print(stats.percentileofscore([4,7,6], 3))
print(stats.percentileofscore([2,8,1], 3))`

Comment: row0: stats.percentileofscore([4,7,6], 4)); row1: stats.percentileofscore([4,7,6], 7)); row3: stats.percentileofscore([4,7,6], 6)).  The [score] should be one scale value from the 'Value' column for that row.

Comment: @Lafayette - Thank you for explanation, solution was changed.

Comment: Great.  That's what I am after.  Thanks.